# syntax error near unexpected token error

Tags: vim

Below is my .vimrc file

```
set nocompatible
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tomlion/vim-solidity'
Plugin 'othreaa/yajs.vim'
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent
set wrap
set nobackup
set ruler
syntax on
set number
set tabstop=4
colo desert
syntax on
```

when I type 'source .vimrc' to activate the configuration file, i got the following error message

```
-bash: .vimrc: line 6: syntax error near unexpected 
token `('
-bash: .vimrc: line 6: `call vundle#begin()'
```

I cannot see what is wrong. Can I help?

Comment: You source it from `bash`, You need to source within vim `:source .vimrc`

Answer (score 2):

Bash cannot parse that. You need to use Vim instead, to parse. Open up Vim and type `:source ~/.vimrc` in Normal mode.

Comment: You can also shorten `:source` to `:so` and if you are currently in the `.vimrc` you can just type `:so %` (which means source this current file). Very useful for when you are making changes to .vimrc and want to see the updates to make sure they work right.

Comment: Also, `vim` will automatically source `.vimrc` when it starts. Unless you explicitly want to source it yourself (like when you make changes, as Stun Brick describes), you don't need to do anything.